# CasperJS: Export scraped data to structured Excel or CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am working on a project where I am looping through a series of invoices and scraping a table of data from each invoice. I am writing the code in CasperJS, and have reached a point where I can scrape all of the relevant information and store it in an array, but am having trouble outputting the information into a structured Excel.

The way the code works now is as follows:
1) Captures the URL of every invoice
2) Loops through each link and captures critical information such as Invoice Number, Invoice Date, the name of each product purchased, and the price of each product purchased.

Here is what this part of the code looks like:

```
function getDescriptions() {
  var description = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(3)');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(description, function(elem) {
    return elem.textContent;
  });
}

function getPrices() {
  var price = document.querySelectorAll('#InvoiceDetailGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(4)');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(price, function(elem) {
    return elem.textContent;
  });
}

casper.then(function() {
  for(var z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
    casper.thenOpen(baseURL + links[z]);

    this.wait(2000, function() {
      invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber.concat(this.fetchText('#InvoiceNumber'));
      invoiceDate = invoiceDate.concat(this.fetchText(x('//*[@id="printArea"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')));

      description = description.concat(this.evaluate(getDescriptions));
      price = price.concat(this.evaluate(getPrices));
    });
  }
});
```

The output is correct and would look something like this: invoiceNumber = 1, 2, 3; invoiceDate = Jan 1, 2015, Jan 2, 2015, Jan 3, 2015; description = product X, product Y, product X, product Z, product A, product B, product C; price = $1, $2, $1, $3, $4, $5, $10. I want to put this data in a table that looks like this:

Invoice Number  Invoice Date    Description Price
1   Jan 1, 2015 product X   $1
1   Jan 1, 2015 product Y   $2
2   Jan 2, 2015 product X   $1
2   Jan 2, 2015 product Z   $3
3   Jan 3, 2015 product A   $4
3   Jan 3, 2015 product B   $5
3   Jan 3, 2015 product C   $10

Each invoiceNumber and invoiceDate would be associated with multiple descriptions and prices, and I would like to ensure that relationship is maintained (as seen in the table). Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've updated the post; hopefully it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot map to the final csv table from your current arrays, because there are more prices than invoice numbers.

You can either directly write the data into a file:

```
var sep = ";";
var fs = require('fs');
this.wait(2000, function() {
  var invoiceNumber = this.fetchText('#InvoiceNumber');
  var invoiceDate = this.fetchText(x('//*[@id="printArea"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]'));

  var description = this.evaluate(getDescriptions);
  var price = this.evaluate(getPrices);
  for(var i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
    // assume description and price have the same length
    // append line:
    fs.write("invoices.csv", invoiceNumber+sep+invoiceDate+sep+description[i]+sep+price[i]+"\n", "a");
  }
});
```

or save everything into an array to iterate later over it

```
var invoices = [];
this.wait(2000, function() {
  var invoice = {};
  invoice.number = this.fetchText('#InvoiceNumber');
  invoice.date = this.fetchText(x('//*[@id="printArea"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]'));

  invoice.descriptions = this.evaluate(getDescriptions);
  invoice.prices = this.evaluate(getPrices);
  invoices.push(invoice);
});
```

Comment: You will probably need to tweak that in case the description contains newlines or something like that.